# Could anyone kindly identify this bug for me? Is it harmless?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Details:

- Found by a wall/window in Brooklyn, NY in a house not too far from the beach
- Rooms walls/windows are dusty and spots of mold growing on wall/windows
- size of bug: 2 milimeters

Keywords I've tried in my web search and image search:

- True bugs, ticks, types of house bugs, sowbug, stink bugs, insects that live/grow near mold, flat bugs, dust bugs

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That particular one is dead, so I guess it's completely harmless, a closer picture with different angles would help a lot to identify it  :)